# Why does subdivision cause deformation - pinching on even subdivided mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

I have made a shape, with evenly subdivided quads on the surface. I then add the subdivision modifier on my shape, and the quads have hard edges appearing. So 2 questions I hav.e

1)What is one way to avoid problems in the future when approaching this type of modelling?

2)And Shouldn't the subdivision modifier be smoothing out the mesh, rather than making it seem with hard topology on the mesh?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share you .blend please?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=pVQ97gnP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/pVQ97gnP/)

Comment: the reason is the shrinkwrap modifier. If you disable it and render it, it is smooth

Comment: Forgetting the Low-res version for a moment. The Hi-res version which is its shrink-wrap target already shows this tendency towards un-subdivided  face normals. It looks to me as if at least one of levels of the subdiv that resulted in the Hi-res version was 'Simple', not 'Catmull-Clark', resulting in faces being subdivided flat, not interpolated,